# Character Array of dynamic length

Tags: c++, pointers, nullpointerexception, char

I have written a C++ Function which can be represented as below:
All it does is take a string (this is where it crashes) and reverse it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 cout<<"Enter a string: "<<endl;
 char *str;
 gets(str);
 cout<<"Reversed String is: ";
 for(int i=strlen(str)-1;i>=0;i--)
    cout<<(str[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

I guess there's some kind of memory access violation.

Any clue why this doesn't work?

Error: **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Comment: `char *str;` - you never allocate memory for a string -> you invoke *undefined behavior*. If you are writing in C++ just use `std::string` instead of C-style `char` arrays. (Also [`std::gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets) is deprecated in C++ and was removed in C++14)

Comment: C++ and C aren't the same language. Pick one of them and then try solving your task.

Comment: I removed the C-tag as this is clearly C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) there is way more easier and less error prone solution to this problem via `std::reverse` from `algorithm`. Also its easier to use `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
  std::string input;
  std::cout << "Enter string to reverse: ";
  std::cin >> input;
  std::reverse(input.begin(),input.end());
  std::cout << "Reversed string: " << input << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

If you have to do it via char arrays, try this (you dont even need dynamic memory allocation)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main ()
{
  char input[1024];
  puts("Enter string to reverse: ");
  fgets(input, 1024, stdin);
  std::reverse(input, input + strlen(input));
  printf("Reversed string: %s", input);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't c++ style and I recommend you take a look at the answer from Filip (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903067/4386427)

I'll just address what goes wrong with your code.

When you do

```
char* str;
```

all you get is a pointer that can point to a `char`. You don't get any memory for holding a `char`. Further the value of the pointer variable `str` is uninitialized.

So when you do

```
strlen(str)
```

you read an uninitialized variable and try to treat this uninitialized value as a C-style string. That is undefined behavior and is very likely to cause a program crash.

You need to make sure that `str` is initialized before using it. As you want dynamic memory, you could do:

```
char *str;
str = new(char[100]);  // Initialize str to point to a dynamic allocated
                       // char array with size 100
...
...
delete(str);
```

But again - I wouldn't use this style in c++ code